# Facebook: Get friended fans of page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

basicly I want to rebuild the "You and this page" function. This question has been asked multiple times, but there was no working solution.

I'm trying to get a list of people who are the logged in users friends and like a specific page. I tried the following query with a user access token but got an empty result:

```
SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id=91290503700 AND user_id IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=THE_USERS_ID)&access_token=TOKEN
```

This query returns an empty result, although I have 20 friends who like Inception (91290503700). I know I can query all my friend's likes and check them against the page id, but for 450 friends it just needs a while, even with batch processing (for me it took 14-27 seconds for these nine batches).

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id=PAGE_ID AND uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me())`

This worked great for me with all permissions granted for my user token.  Play around with the permissions to find what permissions you need for this FQL statement to work.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "uid": 95193664134392
    },
    {
      "uid": 91440825654091
    },
    {
      "uid": 96905133509693
    }
  ]
}
```